# Centrar título de ventana modal

Tags: bootstrap

Según la nueva versión de Bootstrap para mostrar una ventana modal se utiliza el siguiente código básico:

```
<div class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Modal body text goes here.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Cómo puedo centrar el Título de la ventana, he intentado poner text-center pero no funciona

```
<h5 class="modal-title text-center">Modal title</h5>
```

Comment: Con la versión 3.4.0 no deberías tener problemas así como lo has hecho en tu título.

Comment: @Edgard pero con la versión 4 sí que hay un problema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Siempre lo he hecho de esta forma:

```
<div class="modal-header">
    <h5 class="modal-title col-11 text-center">Modal title</h5>
    <button type="button" class="close col-1" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
  </div>
```

También luego de experimentar mucho con Bootstrap lo he hecho así:

```
<div class="modal-header">
    <h5 class="modal-title w-100 text-center">Modal title</h5>
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
</div>
```

Comment: En realidad este sería un _hack de diseño_

Answer (score 2):

para versión 4 de Bootstrap. En lugar de `<div class="modal-header">` añade la clase d-block quedando así:

```
 <!-- Modal Header -->
    <div class="modal-header d-block">
      <h4 class="modal-title text-center">Modal Heading</h4>
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
    </div>
```

Comment: En parte esta solución es correcta, solamente se debe tener cuidado con el botón de cierre, pues lo estaríamos dejando al borde (casi por fuera) del `modal-content`

Answer (score 2):

yo lo resuelvo aplicando la propiedad en los dos elementos, así:

```
<div className="modal-header-center">
  <h4 className="modal-title text-center">Modal title center</h4>
  <button type="button" className="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

tan simple como hacer la referencia a la clase titulo y usar css para complementar bootstrap

```
.modal-title{
    text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: Incorrecto, no va a funcionar así como lo indicas.

Answer (score -1):

Intenta agreado la clase `mx-auto` de bootstrap, la cual coloca un margen a la derecha e izquierda.

Asi deberia de quedar tu h5

```
<h5 class="modal-title mx-auto">Modal title</h5>
```

Comment: Esto se aplicaría solamente respecto al ancho del contenido dentro de la etiqueta `h5`. No es una forma correcta de centrarlo.